# Can you call a PHP defined value inside of a function call?

Tags: php

Please look at the example code below, when I run it, the defined part is nottranslated in the header function call, is there a special way to do the syntax or is this exact method not possible?

```
<?PHP
session_start();
define('SITE_URL', 'http://testsddf.com');
$_SESSION['user_role'] = 0;


//if a user is not active, redirect to verification/suspended page
if($_SESSION['user_role'] == 0){
    header('Location: SITE_URL');
}

?>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot do something like this :

```
define('SITE_URL', 'http://testsddf.com');
header('Location: SITE_URL');
```

A constant is not interpolated, inside of a string : it's not a variable *(and you are using single-quote string, so it wouldn't work with a variable either, here)*

You have to use string concatenation, in this situation :

```
define('SITE_URL', 'http://testsddf.com');
header('Location: ' . SITE_URL);
```

And, just to put a link to the manual as a reference, you can take a look at [Variable parsing](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing) : there is nothing there about constants -- even if that's unfortunate.

Comment: hello, I tried your method as well but it still will not work with the defined variable, assuming that this is the only method header('Location: ' . $SITE_URL); and not header('Location: ' . SITE_URL);   and then define $SITE_URL instead of SITE_URL?

Comment: If you are using a define (and, this way, creating a constant), you should not use $ : the $ symbol is for variables only.

Comment: Yes I understand that part, it's just that header('Location: ' . SITE_URL); is not working even with define('SITE_URL', 'http://testsddf.com');

Comment: weird it just started working, must of been some sort of caching issue, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You either need to do...

```
header('Location: ' . SITE_URL);
```

...or...

```
header("Location: SITE_URL");
```

...as single quotes don't expand variables. (See [this manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single) for more info.)

Comment: I have tried this already but it does not seem to work with a defined variable for some reason

Comment: That's because it is not a "defined variable", it is a constant.  When you are inside a string, anything without a variable reference identifier (`$`) is already a constant.  You must break out of a string constant to access the contents of a defined constant.